# Feedback on Stack Overflow Careers "thanks for participating" e-mail

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, email

I recieved a mail from careers@stackoverflow.com today titled "Thanks for participating on Stack Overflow!"

I wanted to feedback that this hit my junkmail folder (on Hotmail).

I'm not concerned about the mail itself, and I'm sure it's not junk, but you guys might want to know that it's being seen as junk by Hotmail.

**update**

I subsequenty verified my email address on Careers, and then paid to be listed. Both mails associated with these actions ended up as junk. I've now flagged SO mails as "safe". Very little else ends up in my junk mail (i.e. I don't think I have an overly agressive junk mail filter). Perhaps I'm in a minority, but it would be worth investigating why these mails get flagged as it could cost you business or reputation.

Comment: care to post the text for those of us that didn't get one?

Comment: Was this delivered recently or after having just signed up?  If recently, then I guess I'm not feeling the love...

Comment: I got mine on Jan 7th @ 1am(ish) GMT and I've been around in both SO & had signed up for, but not paid on career's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we did a test to hotmail and indeed it is going to the spam folder -- confirmed.

edit:

Even with [SenderID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_ID) and [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) both properly configured and tested (this is new, the DNS records are in, and the email code will be deployed tonight), **we can't get our Stack Overflow mails through to hotmail.com email addresses** -- they regularly go in the spam folder.

Apparently hotmail is a tough nut to crack...

The autoresponder at check-auth@verifier.port25.com is a great resource for this. Send an email to it with a valid reply address, and it'll tell you what isn't configured properly.

edit:

We requested to be added to the hotmail "ok senders" list and got this response:

> We have added your stackoverflow.com, superuser.com and serverfault.com domains to the Sender ID program. This may take up to 2 business days to be fully replicated in our systems. If you have any questions regarding this please let me know.

We also verified that our SPF records were up to snuff and MS signed off on them.

Comment: Awesome tip on the autoresponder!

Answer (score 10):

Can't speak to Hotmail, but it came safely through to my gmail account.

Comment: Yep, Gmail delivered it safely to me as well

Comment: me too (fifteen)

Comment: hotmail is historically way more of a problem for email delivery, based on the team's personal experience and our internet research

Comment: I used mail-tester.com which gave me 10/10 score. Also all passed for mail sent to check-auth@verifier.port25.com . Still hotmail is not showing mails in Inbox or Junk. In my cases, mails are getting lost as they got routed to blackhole!

Comment: @rahul286 who are you talking to? What are you referring to? This question and answer is referring to a StackOverflow "bug" from almost four years ago. If you are asking a question about sending email, you should ask that on StackOverflow (if you're sending programatically) or ServerFault (if you're a network admin)

Comment: I came here looking for solution to mail-server issues from hotmail only. I am referring to hotmail not accepting mails while every other service is "accepting" mail. I am not asking a question. I am just going through similar experience so I decided to share. I have a problem but I will investigate further before posting about it on ServerFault (as it's not programming question).